# Keeping the hose on a hydration bladder from unscrewing?

Tags: hydration-bladders

I have a hydration bladder with a screw on the drinking hose, and the problem is that given enough time it will come unscrewed and then leak inside my backpack.

I have tried tightening it as hard as I dare, (everything is made of plastic) and it still eventually comes loose.

I could live with a permanent solution, since its fairly uncommon to have to remove the hose, and yet I would prefer something that can be undone if possible.

How can I keep the hose on my hydration bladder from unscrewing?

Comment: Does the hose screw into the bladder or onto something that is sticking out of the bladder?

Comment: I wonder if [threadlocker](https://www.amazon.com/Permatex-19920-Plastic-Threadlocker-10/dp/B003ERTZWA) would work. Not posting as an answer since I haven't used it myself.

Comment: @Willeke It sticks out of the bladder just a little bit

Comment: Sorry @CharlieBrumbaugh, in that case my idea will not work.

Comment: If it is a threaded connection you could try a light wrap of plumbers tape. It is made to seal threads from water after all. Although i don't think it is considered food grade so you may want to look into that aspect of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked into it a bit more and I would recommend trying a **light coat of plumber's tape on the threads of the hose connection.**

> Pipe thread tape, or 'plumbing tape' is made from Polytetrafluoroethylene (PTFE). A non-toxic and stable synthetic fluoropolymer

[Source](http://www.electrotape.com/teflon-tape.aspx)

[image: hydration bladder hose wrapped with thread tape]

The trick is to wrap it the same way as the you tighten.

PTFE, It is also used in non-stick coatings on kitchenware so for a non-heated application I would say it would be just fine to use.

Comment: That's a good idea. You could always leave a bit of the tape in your pack too in case repairs are needed.